# Выделение блока при наведении на определенный участок

Tags: javascript

Как сделать с помощью JS изменение всего блока при наведении только на кнопку?

Весь блок с помощью Hover я знаю как поменять, интересует конкретно с помощью JS.

[image: Блоки на сайт]

P.S. Можно и на простом примере, т.к. стили уже готовы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На JavaScript

```js
var button = document.querySelector('button');
var div = document.querySelector('div');
button.onmouseover = function(e) {div.style.background = 'red';};
div.onmouseout = function(e) {div.style.background = 'green';};
```

```css
.div {padding: 50px; background: green;}
```

```html
<div class="div"><button class="button">Кноп</button></div>
```

И ещё один вариант с добавлением класса:

```js
var button = document.querySelector('button');
var div = document.querySelector('div');
button.onmouseover = function(e) {div.classList.add('red');};
div.onmouseout = function(e) {div.classList.remove('red');};
```

```css
div {padding: 50px;}
.green {background: green;}
.red {background: red;}
```

```html
<div class="green"><button class="button">Кноп</button></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Все заработало

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(".block .readmore").hover(function() {
    $(this).parents(".block").toggleClass("active"); 
 })
```

```css
.block{
    padding: 5px 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    background: #FFCA00;
    margin: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    
}
.block_content{
  color: black;
}
.block.active .block_content{
  color: white;
}
.block.active{
    background: #77EEC3;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
<div class="block_content">Какой то текст</div>
    <button class="readmore">подробнее</button>

</div>
<div class="block">
<div class="block_content">Какой то текст</div>
    <button class="readmore">подробнее</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Все заработало

Answer (score 0):

запустите у себя в консоли этот скрипт и наведите на иконку страницы **StackOverflow** для наглядного примера:

```
document.querySelector('._glyph').addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
});

document.querySelector('._glyph').addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = ''
});
```

Comment: При отведении курсора фон не возвращается на место, я думаю автору вопроса нужно чтобы это происходило

Comment: @VitaliyAntal, я просто пытался не давать полный ответ, а намекнуть откуда начинать, дабы пробудить пытливый ум. но всё равно поправил, спасибо за внимание)